# Street labels too close

Tags: arcgis-desktop, maplex

Finally have gotten profecient at maplex labelingg and tweaking each option however, I am running into the issue of some labels appearing too close to each other and they are always duplicates. However, I want to keep duplicating street names every 3 inches. Any ideas?

Referring to the Fort Meade Road in yellow 2 times.

[image: Sample map]

Comment: Why CAPS? for Road/Street names?

Comment: It's for a fire engine for routing so has to be bold to see at night

Comment: I would still use Title Case see Here Maps night mode http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#map-tiles__base-map-styles-and-modes Title Case is faster to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Placement Properties and go to the Label Density tab.

First, check the "remove duplicates" box and then open the Duplicate Labels Options window. Set the search radius to the *minimum* acceptable distance between labels (perhaps 2.5 inches in your case).

Second, check the "repeat label" box and then open the Label Repetition Options windows. Set the minimum repetition interval to to the *maximum* acceptable distance between labels (perhaps 3.5 inches in your case).

Third, ensure that the "connect features" box is checked, so that Maplex effectively views adjacent lines with the same name as the same line.

This will guarantee a label every 2.5" to 3.5" along roads with the same name.